# Only my last form row is being registered in the post when using jquery to add rows dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

I use this code to add rows to a form, the problem is when the form is posted (and the user has added the rows using JS by clicking on the plus icon) it will only return the last posted value:

```
    //Order Form
$("#add").click(function() {
    counter++;
    var cln = $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
    cln.find("[id^='prodcode'], [id^='meterage']").each(function(i, val) {
        val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
    });
    cln.insertAfter('#ordertable tbody>tr:last');
    $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last input').val('');
    $('td.imgsample:last a').remove();
    return false;
});
```

and the form

```
<form id="orderform" name"orderForm" action="tomypage.php" method="post">
<a  id="add">+</a>
 <table id="ordertable" width="533" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">Product Code (e.g 66203)</td>
      <td width="33%">mtrs sq Required (e.g 10)</td>
      <td width="33%">Preview Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode" id="prodcode" /></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage" id="meterage" /></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit your data, `<form>` elements are serialized by `name`, not `id`.  I'd actually remove the `id`s here and just deal with the `name` attributes, like this:

```
cln.find("[name^='prodcode'], [name^='meterage']").each(function(i, val) {
    val.name = val.name.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
});
```

If you need the `id` for another reason, just add a `.name` setter in what you have currently:

```
cln.find("[id^='prodcode'], [id^='meterage']").each(function(i, val) {
    val.name = val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick!  Stupid  question in hindsight :)